# In LINQPad can you access SYSOBJECTS using LINQ?

Tags: .net, linq, linqpad

In LINQPad is there any way to access either the SYSOBJECTS table or the various INFORMATION_SCHEMA.xxx views using LINQ?

I spend a lot of time searching through our huge company database for partial names as there are too many tables and Stored Procedures to remember the names of them all.

I know I can enter and run SQL in LINQPad but I would like to do this in LINQ instead of SQL as LINQ is more fun :)

Thanks

Xanthalas

Comment: Update: since this question was posted, LINQPad has been updated to allow querying of system tables natively. Simply check 'Include System Views and SPs' in connection properties; you'll then see all the system views and SPs in the Schema Explorer, which you can right-click to query.

Comment: I don't see support for 'System Views and SPs' in SQL Azure? Is that coming in new versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new table with the contents of SYSOBJECTS and then search within the new table

```
select * into SYSOBJECTS_COPY from SYS.OBJECTS

from o in SYSOBJECTS_COPY.AsEnumerable()
where Regex.IsMatch( d.Name, "partialName", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase )
select o
```

Comment: The only downside I can see to this is that the copy would go stale as changes were made to the database and so would need refreshing periodically. This wouldn't be a big deal for me though so it is a good solution. Thanks gweddington.

Comment: That's a good point, it would probably be better to create a view instead of a table.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can.

All you have to do is include system views and SPs in selected connection and use LINQ like following:

```
sys.Sysobjects.Where(sp => sp.Xtype == "P")  // returns SPs
sys.Sysobjects.Where(t => t.Xtype == "U")    // returns Tables
```

or using sys.Views directly [example returns all tables with columns containing string "person" ]:

```
sys.Tables.Join(sys.Columns,
                t => t.Object_id,
                c => c.Object_id,
                (t, c) => new { t, c })
    .Where(x => x.c.Name.Contains("person"))
    .Select(x => new { ObjName = x.t.Name,
                       ChildName = x.c.Name } )
            .Distinct()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also embed SQL into your LINQ statements like so:

```
void Main()
{
    var matches = this.ExecuteQuery<SysObject>("SELECT name, type_desc AS "
                + "TypeDesc FROM [sys].[objects]");

    foreach(var match in matches)
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-30}{1}", (match.Name + ":"), match.TypeDesc);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class SysObject
{
    public string Name;
    public string TypeDesc;
    // etc...
}
```

By default LinqPad doesn't use a monospaced font for results, but you can easily change it by pasting the following bit of css into "Edit -> Preferences -> Results -> Launch Editor"

> body {
>       font-family: Consolas, monospace; }

Comment: I didn't know you could do that with LINQ; that's handy. Thanks Nick.

Answer (score 0):

```
from d in Databases
select d
```

when database connection in LINQPad points to master database.

Comment: That will return all the databases on the server but it won't allow me to search for tables within one of those databases. What I would like is the LINQ equivalent of "select * from SYSOBJECTS where name like '%partialName%' and xtype = 'U'". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This code also returns the object definitions and lets you search within the definition if you want.

```
void Main()
    {
        var matches = FetchObjects(true);

        var searchTerm = "tblName"; //<--Change this to filter for what you are looking for
        bool searchName = true; //search the object name
        bool searchDef = false; //search inside object definition (ie the stored procedure definition)
        TypeDescs typeDesc = TypeDescs.Any; //specify whether you want to limit your search to tables or stored procedures

        matches
            .Where(x=> (
                (searchName && x.Name.Contains(searchTerm)) 
                || (searchDef && (x.ObjectDefinition!=null && x.ObjectDefinition.Contains(searchTerm))) )
                && (typeDesc==TypeDescs.Any || x.TypeDesc == typeDesc.ToString())

                )
            .Select(x=> new {x}).Dump();

    }
    IEnumerable<SysObject> FetchObjects(bool includeDefinitions){
         return this.ExecuteQuery<SysObject>("SELECT Name=convert(varchar(30), name), type_desc AS " 
                    + " TypeDesc "
                    + string.Format(", ObjectDefinition={0}", (includeDefinitions)?"OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(name))":"NULL")
                    + " FROM [sys].[objects]");
    }
    enum TypeDescs {Any, SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE, USER_TABLE}
    class SysObject 
    { 
        public string Name; 
        public string TypeDesc; 
        public string ObjectDefinition;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Nick's answer, [here](https://gist.github.com/skalinets/1e592f45752b02b931f865d24b5bc002) is a snippet that generates table information in markdown and opens it in VS Code.